# Enable Gitlab link redirects for slack

Tags: redirection, noscript, gitlab

We're running a self hosted Gitlab instance and using Slack for communication  at work.

I've run into some issues when trying to follow links to our Gitlab instance posted on Slack (by web-hooks in this case) where ABE would just block the redirection. Since the purpose of the redirect is to strip out the referrer info, I'd rather not disable that feature in Slack as it affects all other links too.

I found **a** solution to this by tweaking the SYSTEM setting in ABE to:

```
# Prevent Internet sites from requesting LAN resources.
Site LOCAL
Accept from LOCAL
Accept GET from slack-redir.net
Deny
```

As I understand it this allows slack-redir.net to do any GET request locally, and I'd prefer to only allow the redirection to gitlab.

Any suggestions on how that might be done are most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex does the trick! It can probably be less greedy but it works quite nicely.

```
# Prevent Internet sites from requesting LAN resources.
Site LOCAL
Accept from LOCAL
Accept GET from git.mydomain.com ^http.:\/\/slack-redir\.net\/link\?url=https\%3A\%2F%2Fgit\.mydomain\.com.*$
Deny
```